# How to write to an xml file in a different package

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
SRC Files
    - mainPackage
        IMFL.java
        performXMLSettings.java
    - XML
        settings.xml
```

I'm trying to write to an xml file located in a different package as seen in the package list above.
The code I use to write to XML file is as seen below:

public class performXMLSettings {

```
    /**
 *
 * @param xml
 * @param root
 * @param equals
 * @return String
 * @throws ParserConfigurationException
 * @throws SAXException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String get(String xml, String root, String tag) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String ret = "";

    InputStream istream = performXMLSettings.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(xml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(istream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //ret = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getNodeValue();

    NodeList settings = doc.getElementsByTagName(root).item(0).getChildNodes();
    for(int j=0;j<settings.getLength();j++) {
        if(settings.item(j).getNodeName().equals(tag)){
            ret = settings.item(j).getTextContent();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
/**
 *
 * @param xml
 * @param root
 * @param tag
 * @param value
 * @throws ParserConfigurationException
 * @throws SAXException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws TransformerConfigurationException
 * @throws TransformerException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public static void set(String xml, String root, String tag, String value) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {

    InputStream istream = performXMLSettings.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(xml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(istream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Node rootTag = doc.getElementsByTagName(root).item(0);
    if(rootTag.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList nl = rootTag.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            rootTag.removeChild(nl.item(i));
        }
    }

    Element element = doc.createElement(tag);
    element.setNodeValue(value);
    rootTag.appendChild(element);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(performXMLSettings.class.getResource(xml).toURI()));
transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

}

When I'm trying to get the info from the xml file, I got what I need, but the writing process does not works. It does not throws any error, but there is nothing new written in the xml file.

This is how I use the writing:

`performXMLSettings.set("/XML/settings.xml", "settings", "host", hst);`

Anybody any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: print xml variable value to see where you are setting the content and show here plz

Comment: You mean where I use the setup code?

Comment: print the value of variable xml to test if you're writting in the correct place?.

Comment: Do you get any exception or errors?

Comment: This is the result:
/XML/settings.xml

Comment: No, I dont get any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, I'm not able to write back to the jar file, which contains the package, only if I'll unpack the Jar, overwrite the xml and then pack again the Jar.